# Dynamically load vue components and resources into browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I have a SPA with multiple " custom modules", let´s say 'Module A' and 'Module B'. These modules are very different in nature, and Module A uses several "complex" Vue components and javascript/typescript files (resources) which is irrelevant to Module B, and vice versa.

The user can choose to switch between these modules. I would like to only load the relevant resoures depending on the the user´s choice, so all of the resources in Module A isn´t cluttering up the browsers memory, when Module B is chosen. I am using Webpack for bundling. Is this possible in a SPA?

Maybe an alternate solution could be to use Vue´s 'v-if' or '<componoent :is ...'. But even though, isn´t all the logic loaded in the browser anyway, because of the way webpack is bundling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Async Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components)

Note that what makes component async is not how it is written (as it may seem from 1st two examples) but how it is imported and used...

```js
new Vue({
  // ...
  components: {
    'ModuleA': () => import('./ModuleA'),
    'ModuleB': () => import('./ModuleB'),
  },
  computed: {
    moduleToUse() {
      return this.someUserPreferrences.activeModule // returns 'ModuleA' or 'ModuleB'
    }
  },
  template: `
   <div><component :is="moduleToUse" /></div>
  `
})
```

Answer (score 2):

## Vue Router Lazy Loading

> I would like to only load the relevant resoures depending on the the user´s choice, so all of the resources in Module A isn´t cluttering up the browsers memory, when Module B is chosen.

There is a term called `Vue Router Lazy-Loading`. The basic concept is that, you can subgroup vue components into separate groups. Say you have two components for Module A (Group A) and two components for Module B(Group B).

```js
const Jan = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-a" */ './Jan.vue')
const Feb = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-a" */ './Feb.vue')
const Mar = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-b" */ './Mar.vue')
const April = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-b" */ './April.vue')
```

By configuring router lazy loading, the four components are not bundled toghter into `xxx-chunk.js`, it will be bundled into `xxx-a.js` and `xxx-b.js` instead.

When you refer to, e.g., `Feb.vue`, which belong to `"group-a"`, only `xxx-a.js` is loaded. In this case, `xxx-b.js` is not loaded at the same time.

[Official Guide](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html)

### My Build

In one of my code repos, I subgrouped the pages into three groups `home_profile`, `terms` and `policy`. These `.vue` pages/components are not all nested into `chunk-vendors.67613a87.js`.

```
 dist\js\chunk-vendors.67613a87.js    78.33 KiB          27.43 KiB
  dist\js\home_profile.0fcdff92.js     23.93 KiB          6.96 KiB
  dist\js\terms.8d1717e3.js            17.48 KiB          6.58 KiB
  dist\js\policy.4da72a5e.js           13.76 KiB          4.90 KiB
```

---

## Router View

> The user can choose to switch between these modules.

Check out Element UI [NavBar](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/menu#navmenu), import it with `:router="true"`. You can set all your page `.vue` to be the children routes under the same parent route.

Comment: Thanks alot, that seems useful, I´ll take a look at it! 